# Importance of the size of the queue in BFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve the following question on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/description/.  The question is:

> Given two words (`beginWord` and `endWord`), and a dictionary
>   `wordList`, we  have to find the length of the shortest transformation
>   sequence from  `beginWord` to `endWord` such that every intermediate
>   word is in the  dictionary, and at each step we can change only one
>   letter.  Thus, if  beginWord='hit' and endWord is 'cog', and dict has 
>   `["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]`, then the answer is `5`.

I am trying to understand the highly upvoted solution (which is better than mine) and is like below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int ladderLength(string beginWord, string endWord, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) {
        wordDict.insert(endWord);
        queue<string> toVisit;
        addNextWords(beginWord, wordDict, toVisit);
        int dist = 2;
        while (!toVisit.empty()) {
            int num = toVisit.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {    //-->why this for loop?
                string word = toVisit.front();
                toVisit.pop();
                if (word == endWord) return dist;
                addNextWords(word, wordDict, toVisit);
            }
            dist++;
        }
    }
private:
    void addNextWords(string word, unordered_set<string>& wordDict, queue<string>& toVisit) {
        wordDict.erase(word);
        for (int p = 0; p < (int)word.length(); p++) {
            char letter = word[p];
            for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++) { 
                word[p] = 'a' + k;
                if (wordDict.find(word) != wordDict.end()) {
                    toVisit.push(word);
                    wordDict.erase(word);
                }
            }
            word[p] = letter;
        } 
    } 
};
```

I understood *almost* the entire solution, I do not understand the intuition behind iterating `toVisit.size()` times.  This is also not a part of the standard BFS algo.  Could someone please point out the intuition behind this loop - what exactly does it do and why the range (0 to 1 less than the size of the queue)?

Comment: The loop is only there in order to compute a correct value for `dist`. It makes it so that all nodes added to the queue at a certain distance from the root are iterated in one go, and then dist is incremented.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOR loop is present to assure that we increment dist only after all words at current dist from beginWord are visited. Another [usecase](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-level-order-traversal-line-line/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the inner for loop that iterates from 0 to size of the queue is that, as the search develops:

- new words are added to the queue you are iterating over,
- while at the same time, the current word is removed from that queue.

This for loop limits the iteration to the words initially in the queue, and ensures that the modifications done to the queue do not affect the current stage of the search.

If you stare at it a little bit longer, you will see what is going on.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int ladderLength(string beginWord, string endWord, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) {
        wordDict.insert(endWord);
        queue<string> toVisit;
        addNextWords(beginWord, wordDict, toVisit);
        int dist = 2;
        while (!toVisit.empty()) {
            int num = toVisit.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                string word = toVisit.front();
                toVisit.pop();                         // <-- remove from front of queue 
                if (word == endWord) return dist;
                addNextWords(word, wordDict, toVisit); // <-- add to back of queue
            }
            dist++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Could you please elaborate: _This for loop limits the iteration to the words initially in the queue, and ensures that the modifications done to the queue do not affect the current stage of the search._?